# How to make MaterializeCSS tabs scrollable when there are more tabs than container's width can contain without scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, material-design, materialize

Given below is an example code (SSCCE) to demonstrate my problem. My problem is that the documentation of MaterializeCSS frontend framework says:

> **Scrollable Tabs** Tabs automatically become scrollable

[**Source**](http://materializecss.com/tabs.html)

But when I actually try it using more tabs than the screen width (or parent) can contain without scrolling, it does NOT work. Tabs DO NOT become *scrollable*.

So what is the solution or workaround for this problem?

This is what they show in their guide:

[image]

This is what I get when I follow their guide to write a test on my local server (Only 4 tabs are showing on screen while there are 11 tabs in total - and they are NOT scrollable):

[image]

```js
$('ul.tabs').tabs();
```

```css
.row {
    background-color: wheat;
}

ul {
  background-color: cyan;
}

li {
background-color: pink;
}

html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




<div class="row">
  <div class="col l12">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab col l3"><a href="tabOne" class="active">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li class="tab col l3"><a href="tabTwo" class="disabled">Tab 2 Disabled</a></li>
      <li class="tab col l3"><a href="tabThree" class="">Tab 3</a></li>
      <li class="tab col l3"><a href="tabFour" class="">Tab 4</a></li>
      <li class="tab col l3"><a href="tabFive" class="">Tab 5</a></li>
      <li class="tab col l3"><a href="tabSix" class="disabled">Disabled Tab 6</a></li>
      <li class="tab col l3"><a href="tabSeven" class="">Tab 7</a></li>
      <li class="tab col l3"><a href="tab Eight" class="">Tab 8</a></li>
      <li class="tab col l3"><a href="tab Nine" class="">Tab 9</a></li>
      <li class="tab col l3"><a href="tab Ten" class="">Tab 10</a></li>
      <li class="tab col l3"><a href="tab Eleven" class="">Tab 11</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>


</div>
<!--.row-->
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this out..... after 3 changes it works...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.tabs').tabs();
  });
```

```css
.row {
    background-color: wheat;
}

ul {
  background-color: cyan;
}

li {
background-color: pink;
}

html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab col l3"><a href="tabOne" class="active">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li class="tab col l3"><a href="tabTwo" class="disabled">Tab 2 Disabled</a></li>
      <li class="tab col l3"><a href="tabThree" class="">Tab 3</a></li>
      <li class="tab col l3"><a href="tabFour" class="">Tab 4</a></li>
      <li class="tab col l3"><a href="tabFive" class="">Tab 5</a></li>
      <li class="tab col l3"><a href="tabSix" class="disabled">Disabled Tab 6</a></li>
      <li class="tab col l3"><a href="tabSeven" class="">Tab 7</a></li>
      <li class="tab col l3"><a href="tab Eight" class="">Tab 8</a></li>
      <li class="tab col l3"><a href="tab Nine" class="">Tab 9</a></li>
      <li class="tab col l3"><a href="tab Ten" class="">Tab 10</a></li>
      <li class="tab col l3"><a href="tab Eleven" class="">Tab 11</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved the problem by adding this to my main style.css

```
.tabs {
     display: flex !important
}
```